# Reshape in a specific way python

Tags: python, numpy

Sorry for a question that will seam very trivial.

So I have a 2D array (shape = (2, 9) which looks like this:

```
a = np.array([[ 1,  1,  1, 40, 40, 40, 80, 80, 80],
              [ 0,  0,  1,  0,  1,  1,  0,  1,  1]])
```

That I would like to turn into that 3D array (shape = (3, 2, 3)):

```
array([[[ 1,  1,  1],
        [ 0,  0,  1]],

       [[40, 40, 40],
        [ 0,  1,  1]],

       [[80, 80, 80],
        [ 0,  1,  1]]])
```

As you can see, in the first array, I want to get the first 3 elements of axis 0 and the first3 elements of axis 1, then I take the 3 next elements of axis 0 and 1. And finally, the last 3 elements of axis 0 and 1.

Does anyone has a tip?
Thanks,
Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
a.reshape((2,3,3)).swapaxes(0,1)
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 1,  1,  1],
        [ 0,  0,  1]],

       [[40, 40, 40],
        [ 0,  1,  1]],

       [[80, 80, 80],
        [ 0,  1,  1]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

```
np.stack(np.array_split(a, [3,6], axis=1))
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 1,  1,  1],
        [ 0,  0,  1]],

       [[40, 40, 40],
        [ 0,  1,  1]],

       [[80, 80, 80],
        [ 0,  1,  1]]])
```